# Error in set up Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to learn Ruby on Rails. 
I have installed Ubuntu in virtualbox under the host system Windows 7 64 bit.
I have set up Ruby and next step I want to set up Rails. After entering the command:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

I got the following messages:

Fetching: minitest-4.7.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: atomic-1.1.13.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
**ERROR:  Error installing rails:**
    **ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**

```
    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
```

/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from extconf.rb:13:in `'

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/atomic-1.1.13/ext/gem_make.out

---

What should I do to solve this situation? I am ready to give any additional info you need.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you read the results file? And why are you using sudo?

Comment: run `which make` for me from the ubunutu bash please

Comment: Please post the entire message. Try these and tell us the output: `make -v` and `gcc -v`. If they both give proper outputs (version of those tools), do this: `sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev libgdbm-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config libffi-dev` Then try installing rails. If that doesnt work do `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev` 

ALL THIS ASSUMING YOU ARE ON UBUNTU or a DEBIAN LINUX.

Comment: @sevenseacat Did you read the results file? And why are you using sudo? – sevenseacat 1 hour ago  Without sudo I get:
:~/rails/blog$ gem install rails
Fetching: atomic-1.1.13.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.

Comment: @Isotope: Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit under VirtualBox. Host is Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: @Isotope run which make for me from the ubunutu bash please     /usr/bin/make

Comment: @stevanity I have done it as you said. And nothing have changed. Yes I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: try running `locate mkmf`. Did you install `ruby-dev` or `ruby1.9.1-dev`

Comment: [link](://pastebin.com/rTVGAb5y) The output of **locate mkmf** is too long to put it here. I saved it at pastebin. 

For the second part: username:~$ whereis ruby1.9.1-dev
ruby1.9: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/bin/X11/ruby1.9.1
So as I can see I have ruby1.9.1-dev because **whereis ruby-dev** gives me nothing.

Comment: I installed ruby-dev and **rails server** still gives me a hint of keys. Nothing's changed.

Comment: I have done it! I have run this server with this instruction(Russian language): [**Instruction**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120368/)

Thanks everyone. This question can be closed.

Comment: Also I have used this vm and have updated it to 11 version. _ttp://railskickstarter.org/boxes/ruby-virtual-box.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I get this error, it's because I forgot to install ruby1.9.1-dev and make.